# Angular service returns empty object

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to make a pretty and user friendly app in angular and i'm at the part where i let the user know stuff is loading when i make ajax requests. What i'm trying to accomplish : i want to create a service that handles the initialization data fetching and pass the data as an object to my controller when it becomes available. Of course, the view isn't displayed until all the initial data my controller needs is available. Here's what i have so far:

app.js

```
var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', ['ngRoute']);

Application.service('Initialize', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $q, $timeout)
{   

    this.serverData = function() 
    {
        $http.get('/packing/scan.action')
            .success(function(data)
            {                         
                return data;
            })
            .error(function(data)
            {
                return data;
            });

    };   

}])


Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

        $routeProvider

            .when('/packing/scan.html', {
                templateUrl: 'packing/scan.html',
                controller: 'PackingScanController as packer',
                resolve: {

                    initData : 'Initialize'   .... etc more code
```

scan.js

```
Application.controller('PackingScanController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', function($scope, $http, initData) {

    var packer = this;

    packer.packedToday = initData.serverData(); ... etc more code
```

Comment: What's the question? I suggest you read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/, because you don't really understand how promises work: your service doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your controller to *wait*, what you need to do is to configure the `resolve` option correctly. For this, you need to have your service return a promise, otherwise the router will not wait.

> `resolve - {Object.<string, function>=}` - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. **If any of these dependencies are promises**, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated.

---

Here's a simplified example:

```
app.service('Initialize', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.serverData = function()
  {
    // return the http promise
    return $http
      .get('config.json')
      // use success/error if needed
      .then(function (response) {
        // make sure, only the response data is used
        return response.data;
      })
    ;
  };
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      template: '<pre>{{ main.initData|json }}</pre>',
      controller: 'MainCtrl as main',
      resolve: {
        // configure with DI
        initData: ['Initialize', function (Initialize) {
          // call the service method, and return the promise
          return Initialize.serverData();
        }]
      }
    })
  ;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function (initData) {
  // initData will be loaded
  this.initData = initData;
});
```

**demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/sOwyHz4yMvwujBWYzOn0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks alot man, your example was well explained and pretty straightforward. Could i somehow pass the said promise directly into the resolve object? Cause i'd like to keep as little logic in the config as possible, because there are gonna be more and more routes. Also, why isn't possible to work with success and error instead of get? I tried it and it returns an object all the way

Comment: @JonathanSzekely A few notes: Personally I use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), with that, there are some syntactic shortcuts with regards to how dependencies can be resolved. As of `$http` I must say, that I'm not quite fond with it not returning a *normal* promise object. Because of that, I usually tend to *hide* the http call inside a service, which only ever returns *real* promises (if one could call them that).

Comment: what's the deal with the "real" and "fake" promise objects?

Comment: @JonathanSzekely That's just words I use. I would call a *real* promise, promises created with `$q`. The problem with `$http` is, that it returns a *decorated* promise (success/error methods). But I don't necessarly want to expose the implementation detail that whatever async. service provides a response, actually uses `$http`.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your service in any controllers so you don't need to pass it via resolve.

```
Application.controller('PackingScanController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Initialize', function($scope, $http, Initialize)
```

For loader normally what I do is I check the availability of the data in template using ng-show

```
<div ng-show="!data">Loading...</div>
<div ng-show="!!data" ng-repeat="d in data">...</div>
```

Any time when you need the loader to show, just set your $scope.data to null and proceed to call your API service.

By the way your service won't work without promise as suggested by other user in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> *All these errors come from the fact that we’re trying to transform an **asynchronous** call into a **synchronous** one.  That is simply not possible.*
>
> serverData() doesn’t return anything anymore.  The return data
>   statement is not returning from serverData().  It’s returning from the
>   anonymous callback function passed to then().
>
> The anonymous callback is not called immediately. It’s called when the
>   response is available. And that happens long after serverData() has
>   returned.

So, 
**1. one way: use callbacks**

```
Application.service('initdata',function($http){
    var serverData = function(callback){
        $http.get('/packing/scan.action').then(function(response){
            callback(response.data);
        });
   };

   return {
       serverData: serverData
   };
});

Application.controller('PackingScanController',function(initdata){
    initdata.serverData(function(serverdata){
       $scope.serverdata = serverdata;
    });
});
```

**2. Second way simply return the HTTP promise, and let the controller deal with it.**

```
Application.service('initdata',function($http){
    var serverData = function(){
        return $http.get('/packing/scan.action');
    };

    return {
        serverData: serverData
    };  
});

Application.controller('PackingScanController',function(initdata){
    initdata.serverData().then(function(response){
        $scope.serverdata = response.data;
    });
});
```

**3.You can also return serverData promise instead of returning http response promise.**

```
Application.service('initdata',function($http){
    var serverData = function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/api/ponies').then(function(response) {
            defer.resolve(response.data);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    };

    return {
        serverData: serverData
    };  
});

Application.controller('PackingScanController',function(initdata){
    initdata.serverData().then(function(response){
        $scope.serverdata = response.data;
    });
});
```